# Tabcontrol with different pages (included in xaml or extern page) as tabcontent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, tabcontrol

Hello and thanks for reading and maybe helping :-)

My Code below with statements.

I have my `MainWindow.xaml` in which I have my `CheckBox` and `TabControl`.

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="2" Name="checkBoxCommon" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedCommon}"/>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.Row="4">
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DpConfigCol>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=DpConfigName}>
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="types:ConfigCommon">
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="types:ConfigAdress">
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="types:ConfigCommon">
                        <TextBlock Text="hallo" Width="150"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="types:ConfigAdress">
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

If I tick my checkbox it will add a new model to my `ObservableCollection()`.

```
private bool _isCheckedCommon;
public bool IsCheckedCommon
{
    get { return _isCheckedCommon; }
    set
    {
        _isCheckedCommon = value;

        if (_isCheckedCommon == true)
        {
            DpConfigCol.Add(new ConfigCommon("Common"));
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (object item in DpConfigCol)
            {
                if (item.GetType().ToString()==typeof(ConfigCommon).FullName.ToString())
                {
                    DpConfigCol.Remove(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I made a binding to my `tabcontrol` with this Collection called `DpConfigCol`.

**And now my question:**

How do I make the properties (from my model: `ConfigCommon`) visible in my `tabcontrol.ContentTemplate`? If there are more than one checkbox with even more Models?
Is there a way to implement in that `Tabcontrol.contentTemplate` more than one Template for more than one model?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; (read only the title)

I also had to develop an app that used tabs once. You can use `<Frame>` inside your tabs and set its `Content` to what ever `XAML page` you want

Comment: But how can i implement that in my .xaml if i have two checkboxes with two different frames?